# Industry standard layout manager

Tags: java, layout

Guys can I ask you based on your experience as a Java programmer what is the commonly used layout manager, perhaps in your office I need to know so that I can prepare myself and study the layout, there are so many layout and right now I just finish the gridbaglayout and I'll go now to the spring layout. And what are the best layout to use, and also tell the advantage and disadvantage of the layout. Sorry I'm beginners on Java.

Answer (score 1):

That's a rather subjective question.

Personally, I love `GridBagLayout`, but I also use `VerticalLayout` from SwingX

Off the top of my head, [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) gets a lot of positive feedback and I believe [JGoodies](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/) gets a mention from time to time.

The problem is, until you actually know what it is you want to do, you won't know the best tool for the job

Comment: tnx. I also read lot of positive comments about this Miglayout maybe I should try that out.